# Unsorted list display as table but remove spaces for first and last item

Tags: html, css, navigation, space

I have the following `HTML` code:

```
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the following `CSS` code:

```
#wrapper {width:960px; margin:0 auto;}

#nav {display: table;width:100%;}
#nav li {display: table-cell;}
#nav li a {display: block;text-align: center; border-bottom:1px solid #f00;margin:0 5px; padding:0 0 15px 0;}
```

This code produces a horizontal menu with a bottom `border`.

Something like..

```
|   Link      Link       Link      Link   |
|_________  _________  _________ _________|
<-----------------  960px  --------------->
```

I wonder if it's possible to remove the spaces for the first and the last item so the bottom `border` begins in a vertical line with the first letter of the first link, and the last letter of the last link. Something like...

```
|Link         Link       Link         Link|
|______     ________   ________     ______|
<-----------------  960px  --------------->
```

Anyone got a nice solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but maybe try doing float:left on your li elements instead of doing display:table and display:table-cell? That way they'll still be horizontally arranged, but you'll be able to do individual styling on the padding of each li and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a couple other styles: firstElement, lastElement. And treat them a little differently

```
    <li id='firstElement'><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li id='lastElement'><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to target the first and last child of the list.

```
ul li:first-child a { margin-left: 0 }
ul li:last-child a { margin-right: 0 }
```

Or, you can have negative margins on your parent container.  I find this works nicer if there's a possibility of the list wrapping (such as on a mobile device).

```
ul { margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px }
```